# Another Java sorting which I am trying to solve

Tags: java, sorting

I have to verify a column of data in html is sorted correctly.  I copy it into a Java list, make a copy which I sort, and compare.  Unfortunately, Java sorts differently than the program which created the table (which also appears to be the same way Excel sorts).  So I wrote a comparator and wondered about comments?  Also I wondered if there is already a class that exists where you give it a character string of ascending characters and it sorts?  Collator might do that but I tried to write it and never got it to work.  Here is my comparator:

```
static class xcomp implements Comparator {
    String cst = "'-–— !\"#$%&()*,./:;?@[\\]^ˆ_`{|}~¡¦¨¯´¸¿˜‘’‚“”„‹›+<=>±«»×÷0123456789AaªÁáÀàÂâÄäÃãÅåÆæBbCcÇçDdÐðEeÉéÈèÊêËëFfƒGgHhIiÍíÌìÎîÏïJjKklMmNnÑñoºÓóÒòÔôÖöÕõØøŒœPpQqRrSŠšßTtÞþ™UuÚúÙùÛûÜüVvWwXxYyÝýŸÿZzŽž";

    public void xcomp(String sort) {
        cst = sort;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

        if (o1 == null && o2 == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (o1 == null) {
            return -1;
        }

        if (o2 == null) {
            return 1;
        }

        String s1 = (String) o1;
        String s2 = (String) o2;

        int l1 = s1.length();
        int l2 = s2.length();

        if (s1.equals(s2)) {
            return 0;
        }

        int l = Math.min(l1, l2);
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            char c1 = s1.charAt(i);
            char c2 = s2.charAt(i);
            int p1 = cst.indexOf(c1);
            int p2 = cst.indexOf(c2);

            if (p1 == -1 || p2 == -1) {
                p1 = (int) c1;
                p2 = (int) c2;
            }

            if (p1 != p2) {
                return (int) (p1 - p2);
            }
        }

        // Strings are the same so far
        return (l1 - l2);
    }
```

Comment: A backtick is one of the characters in the string so it turned off the code formatting for that short segment.  Sorry about that.

Comment: How's this question related to `selenium`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bug in your comparator.

```
  if (p1 == -1 || p2 == -1) {
       p1 = (int) c1;
       p2 = (int) c2;
  }
```

If `p1` or `p2` is minus one that means that the character is not in your collection sequence.  You either need to bail out (throw an exception), or treat it consistently as "before" or "after" the known characters.  That isn't what you are doing.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure what to do.  What it really means is there is a character I forgot to put in my sort string.  I was just relying on the default sort in that case, but what I really should do is mark it and figure out where in the string it should go.

Comment: *"I was just relying on the default sort in that case ..."* -  Well, that's not what you have implemented.  Read your code again carefully.  What your code actually does is to misinterpreted the unknown character as an index in the collation sequence!

Comment: I actually removed that whole if.  If a character is not there its value will be -1 and will be sorted before any other character starting with 0 (or is it 1)?